# opencv 3.0 beta with python 3.4 (windows7)

Tags: python, opencv, 64-bit

This is essentially a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252077/opencv-3-0-install-on-windows-x64-python-3-4) which I don't feel like was adequately answered. I was able to install opencv3.0 beta on my ubuntu with Python3.4 with minimal difficulty. On windows, I can not figure out how to do this.

The self extracting archive for windows [here](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-beta.html) downloads and builds the files, but only a python/2.7 folder is present (containing the pyd file). Not a 3.x.

What I would like to know is 1)Is this setup currently supported. 2) if not, when could I expect it to be supported?

-Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's possible using Windows installer but definitely you can do it if you build Opencv 3.0 from source. Using CMake-gui and Visual Studio (other compilers should work fine as well) is quite easy, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) you can read more about it (tutorial is for version 2.4.9, but it's "working" for 3.0 as well). Generally CMake should find python without any help, but if it fails, configuring it won't be a real problem.

Comment: That was also suggested in the SOquestion I linked, but the author and myself were flummoxed because it says "The Python libraries are required to build the Python interface of OpenCV. For now use the version 2.7.x. This is also a must if you want to build the OpenCV documentation."

Comment: This seemed to suggest strongly to me that it only worked with Python2.7

Comment: This tutorial comes straight from documentation of OpenCV 2.x and some informations might be obsolete. I've build OpenCV 3.0.0 from source on Windows and i remember that there are options "Python 2" and "Python 3" so most likely it is possible to use Python 3.x. I've not tried that, but i think that OpenCV developers  included such option for some reason :) Of course first you need to install Python 3, numpy and all other required python libraries on you own (use `pip` it's really good tool for managing python libs), but after that you should be able to build(from source) Opencv with Python3.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. My python3 version is the one provided from WinPython. (as a newbie) it's a shame I can't just do "pip install opencv"